# HTML-Email Builder using available content

Tags: theming, 8, emails

I'm building a content marketing system in drupal 8 and I'm looking for a way to let editors put Media and Blocks in some kind of template which is then exported as an html email.

Right now I am using Display Suite and Entity References to let editors build landing pages. On a landing page, one, two or three column blocks can be referenced. In theses rows editors can reference media entities (texts, images, videos).

What I would do is do the same in a content type called html-email. For this content type I would try to get rid of all the twig markup and insert my html email markup. I would then let the editor copy the section with the email markup from the source code of each page so they can copy it in whatever email tool they are using. The necessary css files would be added there, the inline css and all the nasty html markup would go in the twig templates.

Is this goint to work? Do you have other (simpler) suggestions? The important thing is, that users can use the content, which is already in the system and add one, two or three column layouts as rows to their liking.

Thanks!